# Little confused on subtracting uint16_t values

Tags: c++, memory-management, casting, uint16

So i am trying to subtract two uint_16 values from one another and every time i do it i get an error.

```
conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t', signed/unsigned mismatch
```

```
uint16_t a = 432;
uint16_t d= 60000;
uint16_t total = d -a;
```

I know you would need to cast it but how so,and wouldn't their be an loss of data when doing so.

Comment: Which line of the code?

Comment: i get an error on the third line when i compile

Comment: It's at most a warning, not error

Answer (score 2):

`uint16_t` most likely has a lower integer rank than `int`. It is probably an alias for `unsigned short`.

If that is the case, then [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) will be applied to `d` and `a` before they are subtracted.

Integral promotion will try to convert `unsigned short` to `int` if `int` can hold all possible values of `unsigned short`. Only if that is not the case will integral promotion to `unsigned int` be performed.

Therefore the subtraction is most likely done in the type `int`, not `uint16_t`.

The warning is then telling you that you are casting that signed `int` result to an unsigned type (`uint16_t`) when you initialize `total` with it, which is normally not what you want to do, because unsigned types cannot store negative values that a signed type might hold.

---

If it *is* possible that the subtraction yields a negative value, then you should not be using `uint16_t` at all. Instead you should manually cast the operands to a suitable signed integral type and store the result as a suitable signed integer type (i.e. `int` or `int32_t`):

```
int32_t total = static_cast<int32_t>(d)-static_cast<int32_t>(a);
```

or

```
auto total = static_cast<int32_t>(d)-static_cast<int32_t>(a);
```

for a bit less repetition.

If you guarantee that the subtraction doesn't yield any negative values, then you can add a `static_cast` to tell the compiler that you really know what you are doing:

```
uint16_t total = static_cast<uint16_t>(d-a);
```

or

```
auto total = static_cast<uint16_t>(d-a);
```

if you don't want to repeat the type name.